# VueJS, ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2, vue2-google-maps

I have the following source code and I got also the following error when I try to instantiate a new var with `google.maps ...`:

> google' is not defined

Many of the answers talked about loading the API script asyncronously before everything else, and the order of the scripts matters, but I don't think that's my issue.

PS: I use this in the `main.js`

```vue
Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {    
  load: {    
    key: 'MY-KEY',    
    libraries: 'places', //// If you need to use place input    
  },    
})
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

```vue
<div class="map-container">     
       <gmap-map     
         id="map"     
         ref="map"     
         :center="center"     
         :zoom="15"     
         map-type-id="roadmap"     
         style="width:100%;  height: 400px;">     
           <gmap-marker     
           :key="index"    
            v-for="(m, index) in markers"    
            :position="m.position"    
             @click="center=m.position"    
             ></gmap-marker>    
                </gmap-map>
            </div>
```

```js
<script>    
    import _ from 'lodash'    
    import { mapState } from 'vuex'    
    import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps'   

    export default {    
      computed: {    
        ...mapState([    
          'map',    
        ]),    
        mapStyle: function () {     
          const h = document.body.clientHeight - 80    
          return 'width: 100%; height: ' + h + 'px'    
        },    
        center: function () {    
          return { lat: 44.837938, lng: -0.579174 }    
        },    
      },    
      mounted: function () {    
        VueGoogleMaps.loaded.then(() => {
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'))    
        }
      },
```

Comment: From looking through some of the source code, it *seems* to me that the plugin doesn't expose an api and that It uses `google` as a global, so it expects it to be loaded outside of the library. You may be able to get it to work if you use `window.google` but only if that library is loaded separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have imported everything as `VueGoogleMaps` I would assume that `google` is within this object.

EDIT: Seems that `google` object is called `gmapApi`.

So change

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'))
```

to

```
let map = new VueGoogleMaps.gmapApi.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'))
```

Since you are not importing anything explicitly it should all rest within `VueGoogleMaps`. So if you want to have it called `google`, add the computed field as described in the other answer, except that `gmapApi` should sit within `VueGoogleMaps`.

So

```
computed: {
    google: VueGoogleMaps.gmapApi
}
```

Comment: Looks like you may be referencing info from `vue-google-maps`. Doesn't look like `vue2-google-maps` has an api

Answer (score 2):

You forgot one parenthesis:

```
VueGoogleMaps.loaded.then(() => {
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'))    
        })
```

Tell me if this helps.

---

Also from [NPM vue2-google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps),

> If you need to gain access to the `google` object:
>
> ```
> <template>
>   <GmapMarker ref="myMarker"
>     :position="google && new google.maps.LatLng(1.38, 103.8)" />
> </template>
> <script>
> import {gmapApi} from 'vue2-google-maps'
>
> export default {
>   computed: {
>     google: gmapApi
>   }
> }
> </script>
> ```

Comment: It doesnt help his problem. I have posted a similar answer and removed it as it didnt solve the issue.

Comment: Edited my post: There is one parenthesis missing. I got it working in a CodeSandbox.

Comment: @charlycou yes, i used "Matthias S" answer to solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

If you get "**maps of null**" it means google computed property is not ready yet.

Try this:

```
computed: {
    google: VueGoogleMaps.gmapApi
}
...
```

Inside your method to wait for gmapApi:

```
this.$gmapApiPromiseLazy().then(() => {
  //your code here
  //E.g. for directions
  var directionsService = new this.google.maps.DirectionsService();
});
```